# Acceso de usuarios sin correo a web app desarrollada en google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, aplicación-web

Existe forma de que un usuario pueda acceder a una web app sin tener correo, es decir que solo acceda al link e ingrese. He probado dandole acceso a 'cualquiera' en la implementación de google apps script pero no funciona, me redirige a la pagina de login de google.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que haya un problema de permisos con alguna de las herramientas que estés usando en tu WebApp.

Te muestro un ejemplo donde funciona, consiste en mostrar el contenido de una Hoja de Google en una tabla HTML en la WebApp.

OJO con los permisos, no des acceso indiscriminado a tu contenido de Google, a no ser que debas hacerlo.

Para manejar el tema de los permisos de una forma más fácil haz visible el archivo de manifiesto de tu WebApp yendo a **`Configuración`** y activando la opción `Mostrar el archivo de manifiesto`. Al hacerlo, verás un archivo llamado `appsscript.json` en tu lista de archivos del editor con un contenido parecido a este:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

Ahí están todos los permisos otorgados para este caso, incluyendo el acceso anónimo. En el apartado `oauthScopes` he dado sólo este permiso: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`, significa que se tendrá acceso solamente a las Hojas que estén asociadas a esa WebApp. Si trabajas con otra cosa: Documents, Forms, etc, tendrás que dar los permisos correspondientes según lo que quieras hacer. Para más detalles [lee la documentación sobre los permisos](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes).

Con esto debería funcionar, una vez implementes tu WebApp. No olvides copiar la URL que se genera cuando implementas (al final de la pantalla de implementación).

#### Demo

[Aquí tienes la URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxoFVBcwpnF3ikA7DmigOzShJVzH2dO4xSQW6mGHhytKXdR0pMYjF1mKIJeMHritwqW/exec) de una WebApp funcionando.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta¡¡ :D